# How to style with Y.StyleSheet

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet, yui

I am trying to style an element using Y.StyleSheet.

This is how I am currently doing it, and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/AxUMD/47/

```
document.documentElement.className += ' js';

Y.one('#techsolutionsCheckBox input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
    var target = e.currentTarget,
        techSBox = Y.one('.box'),
        techSBlueBox = document.getElementById( 'techsolutions' );
        colourBlue = "#cee4f2",
        colourWhite = "#ffffff";

    if (target.get('checked')) { 
       techSBox.removeClass('hidden');
       techSBlueBox.style.backgroundColor = colourBlue;
       techSBlueBox.style.width = "380px"; 
       techSBlueBox.style.height = "100px";
    } else {
        techSBox.addClass('hidden');
        techSBlueBox.style.backgroundColor = colourWhite;
        techSBlueBox.style.width = null; 
        techSBlueBox.style.height = null;
    }
});
```

but this is how I would like to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/AxUMD/57/
but it is not working as I thought it would.

```
document.documentElement.className += ' js';

Y.one('#techsolutionsCheckBox input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
    var target = e.currentTarget,
        techSBox = Y.one('.box'),
        techSBlueBox = Y.one(Y.DOM.byId("#techsolutions")),
        changesChecked = { background-color : '#cee4f2', width : '380px', height : '100px' },
        changesUnChecked = { background-color : '#ffffff', width : null, height : null },
        currentStyle = techSBlueBox.getStyle('cssText');

    if (target.get('checked')) { 
       techSBox.removeClass('hidden');
       techSBlueBox.setStyle('cssText', Y.StyleSheet.toCssText(changesChecked, currentStyle));
    } else {
        techSBox.addClass('hidden');
        techSBlueBox.setStyle('cssText', Y.StyleSheet.toCssText(changesUnChecked, currentStyle));
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou, I have achieved the same by using a css class:

```
.showBlueBox {
    background-color:#cee4f2;
    width : 370px;
    height : 100px;
}
```

and then added this code to use the styles:

```
techSBlueBox.addClass('showBlueBox');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is basically working it seems but has a few syntax issues.

1) Dashes in JavaScript object properties cause those properties to have to be quoted. So "background-color" needs quotes around it.

2) Your construction for getting the Node instance for #techsolutions isn't working, but can be greatly simplified to just Y.one("#techsolutions")

3) Your fiddle needs to have loaded Y.Stylesheet before executing the code so that the static method exists. Adding "stylesheet" (the module name) to your YUI().use() call or wrapping your code in an additional Y.use will fix that.

```
document.documentElement.className += ' js';

Y.use("stylesheet", function (Y) {
    Y.one('#techsolutionsCheckBox input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
        var target = e.currentTarget,
            techSBox = Y.one('.box'),
            techSBlueBox = Y.one(Y.DOM.byId("#techsolutions")),
            changesChecked = { "background-color" : '#cee4f2', width : '380px', height : '100px' },
            changesUnChecked = { "background-color" : '#ffffff', width : null, height : null },
            currentStyle = techSBlueBox.getStyle('cssText');

        if (target.get('checked')) { 
           techSBox.removeClass('hidden');
           techSBlueBox.setStyle('cssText', Y.StyleSheet.toCssText(changesChecked, currentStyle));
        } else {
            techSBox.addClass('hidden');
            techSBlueBox.setStyle('cssText', Y.StyleSheet.toCssText(changesUnChecked, currentStyle));
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brianjmiller/AxUMD/128/